# QueryFrame very slow on Windows

Tags: python, windows, performance, opencv

I have build a simple webcam recorder on linux which works quite well.
I get ~25fps video and good audio.

I am porting the recorder on windows (win7) and while it works, it is *unusable*.
The QueryFrame function takes something more than 350ms, i.e 2.5fps.

The code is in python but the problem really seems to be the lib call.

I tested on the same machine with the same webcam (a logitech E2500). 
On windows, I installed openCV v2.2. I cannot check right now but the version might be a bit higher on Ubuntu.

Any idea what could be the problem ?

edit : I've just installed openCV2.4 and I have the same slow speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is really on `QueryFrame` I suspect the following might be happening: the Windows' driver for your camera retrieves the frames in a format that is not natively supported by OpenCV, so OpenCV is forced to convert the frames to a format that it understands. This operation consumes CPU and you would notice a performance loss if the size of the frames are big.

For testing purposes, you can:

**1)** Set a smaller size for the frames and see if it improves the performance:

```
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
```

**2)** Use another camera and see if the problem goes away.

Once you've determined that this is really what's going on, try to find an update for the driver and hope that it solves the issue, or stop using Windows. =)

Comment: @karlphilip :  `or stop using Windows`... I like that :). By the way, which one do you use? Fedora? Ubuntu?

Comment: Fedora/Ubuntu/Mac OS X. But I have a couple of Windows VMs for testing my cross-platforms applications. And you?

Comment: @karlphilip : Usually fedora. Windows rarely.

Comment: @karlphilip : sent you the mail

Comment: @karlphillip :thank you, the reduced size helpd but the core of the issue seems deeper. I have now sometimes better performance but it seems linked to some driver setup. I'll update the main text once I have a better understanding of what happen. About stopping using windows, I did, long ago but my current customer didn't...

Comment: @LionelBarret No need to thank me, just upvote the answer if it was helpful. By the way, given the new info that you discovered (based on my answer), I fear that your *update* of the question will change the question considerably. As this behavior is bad practice (since it might render current answers unuseful), I suggest you consider asking the new question in a different thread, and close this thread officially.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and I found out that this is caused by prolonged exposure. It may be the case that Windows drivers increased exposure to increase brightness of picture. Try to point your camera to light source or manually set decreased exposure